# Need to calculate the salary on the basis of attendance in odoo16

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

i have use this code in the salary structure to solve my  problem but there are still few things not working according to me.
Code piece 1:
by using this code the odoo calculate all the number of days in the column even if they are from unpaid leave which i dont want

`result = 0 for line in payslip.worked_days_line_ids:      result += line.number_of_days result = result*(contract.wage/30)`

Code piece 2: in this code it calculate the salary on the number of days attendance but again in this it ignore all the paid leaves/sick leave days.

`result = worked_days.WORK100.number_of_days * (contract.wage / 30)`

i want to calculate the salary on the bases of attendance,sick leave,other paid leaves and unpaid leaves.

Comment: well that is complete irrelevant comment . but the answer to your question is sick leaves are paid so this means they don't have to come .

Comment: no they are on leave but get paid.

Comment: i have made some improvement in this problem now got some other as well 
result = 0
for line in payslip.worked_days_line_ids:
    if line.code != 'LEAVE90':
        result += line.number_of_days
result = result * (contract.wage / 30)


by this code it calculate the salary on bases of attandance, paid and unpaid time off but now the problem is if one employee dont get any kind of leave and present for whole month it minus the weekends and its salary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the salary based on attendance, sick leave, other paid leaves, and unpaid leaves, you can use:

**Code piece 1:**

```py
    result = 0
    for line in payslip.worked_days_line_ids:
        if line.code == 'WORK100':
            result += line.number_of_days
        elif line.code == 'LEAVE_UNPAID':
            result -= line.number_of_days
    
    result = result * (contract.wage / 30)
```

**Code piece 2:**

```py
   result = 0
    for line in payslip.worked_days_line_ids:
        if line.code == 'WORK100' or line.code == 'LEAVE_PAID' or line.code == 'LEAVE_SICK':
            result += line.number_of_days
    
    result = result * (contract.wage / 30)
```

Comment: Your Answer is quit good .But I already solve this problem now got the new one this code calculate salary only if the emplyoee is present or the days are paid or unpaid are also mentioned.
But if the employee present for whole month 
e.g total month days =31
total working days =23
total weekends =8
now this code only calculate salary for 23 days and minus the 8 weekends bcz employee dont have attendance.